# Change text value inside AutoComplete Widget when user selects an option

Tags: flutter

I'm using the AutoComplete class and Chip class to create an input search field to add tags. Now, when the user selects an option, it's chip gets added and displayed(as intended), but the textfield is not cleared. The user now has to empty the textfield themselves to add another option. I wan to clear the text inside the field when an option is selected. Here is my code -

```dart
autoComplete() {
  var controller = Get.find<IntroForm3Controller>();
  return Autocomplete<String>(
    optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
      if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
        return const Iterable<String>.empty();
      }
      return myOptionsList.where((String option) {
        return option.startsWith(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase()) && !controller.mySelectedOptionsList.contains(option);
      });
    },
    onSelected: (String selection) {
      controller.mySelectedOptionsList.add(selection);
      
      // I want to implement this line somehow
      //textController.text = "";
    },
    fieldViewBuilder: (context, textController, focusNode, onFieldSubmitted) {
      return TextField(
        controller: textController,
        focusNode: focusNode,
        autofillHints: diseases,
        
      );
    },
  );
}
```

I tried using the fieldViewBuilder inside AutoComplete but I can not pass my own attributes to it.

Edit : Here is the code for my View class (although i don't think it will be necessary) -

```dart
class IntroForm3View extends GetView<IntroForm3Controller> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Select Tags'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Form(
          key: controller.formKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: autoComplete(),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: Get.width,
                  child: Obx(() => chipList(controller.mySelectedOptionsList)),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Get.toNamed(Routes.HOME);
                    },
                    child: Text("Skip")),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (controller.formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        print("form validated");
                        Get.toNamed(Routes.HOME);
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text("Continue")),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and it's controller class -

```dart
class IntroForm3Controller extends GetxController {
  List<String> mySelectedOptionsList = ["Option 1", 'Option 2'].obs;
  TextEditingController textController = new TextEditingController();
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {}
}
```

Comment: I think you should try to clear textController like textController.clear() when you add tags in a list

Comment: @TusharPatel I'm only getting access to the textController inside fieldViewBuilder, but I need to use it inside onSelected

Comment: can you share some more code to understand in more detail like your stateful class code?

Comment: @TusharPatel I've added the view and controller code to the question

Comment: Try passing textController in your autoComplete method. Like autoComplete(textController), and in your method autoComplete(TextController 
 anyName){}

Comment: The solution was to use RawAutoComplete. It provides more abstraction so we can pass the controller to the textField.

Comment: I also found a great article to implement a textField with autoComplete - https://medium.com/saugo360/https-medium-com-saugo360-flutter-using-overlay-to-display-floating-widgets-2e6d0e8decb9